# How to fill varargs with range?

Tags: kotlin

What is a proper way to fill varargs? My attempt looks like a bycile
at fist i construct range
then i convert it to list
then to intarray
then spread it

```
m.getColumns(*((count.. count + 35).toList().toIntArray()))
```

where getColums is a method which accepts colums indexes as varargs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, ranges are really far from arrays in this sense, it's rather hard to pass them in as `vararg` parameters.

---

You could create a function to convert them to `IntArray` instances one step quicker:

```
fun IntRange.toIntArray() = this.toList().toIntArray()

m.getColumns(*(count..count + 35).toIntArray())
```

A slightly better optimized version of this conversion:

```
fun IntRange.toIntArray(): IntArray {
    val size = this.last - this.first + 1
    var current = this.first
    return IntArray(size) { current++ }
}
```

---

Or you could define an overloaded function that takes an `IntRange` and does the conversion to call the original:

```
fun getColumns(range: IntRange) = getColumns(*range.toList().toIntArray())
```

Again, this could also make use of the conversion method above for better performance:

```
fun getColumns(range: IntRange) = getColumns(*range.toIntArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

You call varargs method with either a number of comma separated variables or with an array.

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut to making array from a range.

But, you can create an array directly:

```
m.getColumns(*IntArray(35) { count + it })
```