# Kotlin Initializing Int Array with Ranges

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Is there a way to initialize an array in Kotlin in this way with a range and mixed numbers.

```
intArrayOf(4, 10, 3, 20..24)
```

The contents of the array should be [4, 10, 3, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill varargs with range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472628/how-to-fill-varargs-with-range)

Comment: 20..24 have type intRange, so you should firstly convert type intRange to Int type. I think you making some kind of bicycle bro ).

Comment: Marvin I found something that let me do it like this
intArrayOf(4, 10, 3) + IntArray(5) { 20 + it }
but then I would have to count the number of elements in the range and put it as the size every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intArrayOf(4, 10, 3, *((20..24).toList().toIntArray()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer by @ardenit, you can make it a bit more appealing like so:

```
fun IntRange.arr() = this.toList().toIntArray()

fun main() {
    intArrayOf(4, 10 , *(20..24).arr(), *(90 until 95).arr()) // [4, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]

}
```